# OpenVPN GUI Fails with "Adapter not found"

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect using `OpenVPN` to a remote destination from two different locations, one works, while the other one does not.

The log file of each is identical except for the `Key` line in the failed location. I am giving the lines immediately before and immediately after.

2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=572618 [netgear] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=395618 Key [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974 [0] not initialized (yet), dropping packet.
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=395618 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098840,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,

The next 16 log lines are identical. The last identical line is the `open_tun` line. That is when on the failed location that I see the error lines:

```
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=472616 MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=472616 Adapter 'NETGEAR-VPN' not found
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=472616 Exiting due to fatal error
```

The OpenVPN connection uses two ports: 12973 and 12974. Both are open on the failed side. I used [Port Forward Network Utility](https://portforward.com) to verify the port on the client side.

The log file on the failed end shows that it does indeed communicate with the server, just does not continue. I know that for several reasons. The most obvious is the `10.0.0` subnet. That subnet is on the server end. There are other indications.

My guess is that I am not doing something.

1. I opened up both OpenVPN ports on the client
2. I installed the OpenVPN GUI v11.23.0.0 software
3. I copied the config files to the config folder on both systems
4. Connect (even tried reboots), just does fails at the same spot.

(I even tried importing both CRT on the client side, though I did not have to do that on the working location.

**Working Log**

```
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=94634 OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Feb 24 2021
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=94634 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=94634 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=97626 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=97626 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=594298 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=697024 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=698021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=725947 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=725947 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=726944 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=726944 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=728938 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=742901 LZO compression initializing
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=742901 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1654 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=742901 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098988,RESOLVE,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1654 D:1450 EF:122 EB:411 ET:32 EL:3 ]
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 UDP link local: (not bound)
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=783792 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098988,WAIT,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=840640 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098988,AUTH,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=840640 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974, sid=4166d822 29a81d79
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=953339 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=TW, ST=TW, L=Taipei, O=netgear, OU=netgear, CN=netgear, emailAddress=mail@netgear.com
2021-04-10 16:56:28 us=954336 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=netgear
2021-04-10 16:56:29 us=90971 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 1024 bit RSA
2021-04-10 16:56:29 us=90971 [netgear] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=343623 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098990,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=344620 SENT CONTROL [netgear]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0,route-delay 5,route-gateway dhcp,ping 10,ping-restart 120'
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 Using peer cipher 'AES-128-CBC'
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 Outgoing Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=372546 Incoming Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=373543 interactive service msg_channel=592
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=374540 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 I=24 HWADDR=18:c0:4d:2b:bd:2d
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=381522 OpenVPN ROUTE: OpenVPN needs a gateway parameter for a --route option and no default was specified by either --route-gateway or --ifconfig options
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=381522 OpenVPN ROUTE: failed to parse/resolve route for host/network: 10.0.0.0
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=381522 open_tun
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=384513 tap-windows6 device [NETGEAR-VPN] opened
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=384513 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24 
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=384513 TAP-Windows MTU=1500
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=384513 Successful ARP Flush on interface [27] {FBAA17FE-1668-40B7-9A9A-C4DBF374D6AA}
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=384513 do_ifconfig, ipv4=0, ipv6=0
2021-04-10 16:56:30 us=384513 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098990,ASSIGN_IP,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:56:31 us=5852 Extracted DHCP router address: 10.0.0.1
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=4165 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=4165 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 172.88.131.44 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=5162 Route addition via service succeeded
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=5162 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=7156 Route addition via service succeeded
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=7156 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=8154 Route addition via service succeeded
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=8154 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=8154 Initialization Sequence Completed
2021-04-10 16:56:35 us=8154 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098995,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,,172.88.131.44,12974,,
```

**Failed Log**

```
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=55586   disable_nbt = DISABLED
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=55586 OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Feb 24 2021
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=55586 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=55586 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=57586 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=57586 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=68589 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=198586 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=204587 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=834588 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=848587 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=861588 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=868586 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=870586 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=886587 LZO compression initializing
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=887588 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1654 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=887588 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098838,RESOLVE,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1654 D:1450 EF:122 EB:411 ET:32 EL:3 ]
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 UDP link local: (not bound)
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:53:58 us=942585 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098838,WAIT,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=271616 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098839,AUTH,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=271616 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974, sid=625f3ee8 ea11b3a0
2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=419615 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=TW, ST=TW, L=Taipei, O=netgear, OU=netgear, CN=netgear, emailAddress=mail@netgear.com
2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=420615 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=netgear
2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=572618 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 1024 bit RSA
2021-04-10 16:53:59 us=572618 [netgear] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=395618 Key [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974 [0] not initialized (yet), dropping packet.
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=395618 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1618098840,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=395618 SENT CONTROL [netgear]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=431616 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0,route-delay 5,route-gateway dhcp,ping 10,ping-restart 120'
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 Using peer cipher 'AES-128-CBC'
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 Outgoing Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 Incoming Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=432619 interactive service msg_channel=600
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=437614 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 I=14 HWADDR=70:54:d2:7e:23:fb
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=460617 OpenVPN ROUTE: OpenVPN needs a gateway parameter for a --route option and no default was specified by either --route-gateway or --ifconfig options
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=460617 OpenVPN ROUTE: failed to parse/resolve route for host/network: 10.0.0.0
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=460617 open_tun
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=472616 MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=472616 Adapter 'NETGEAR-VPN' not found
2021-04-10 16:54:00 us=472616 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you installed the VPN tap drivers on the device which is not working, since that might be the device its looking for?

Comment: @Cruiser what is a VPN tap driver and where does one get that?

Comment: Usually that should be installed when you install openvpn. I looked for an install, but it appears that it is now installed together with the main package, you can no longer install it separately. I would recommend reinstalling [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/). I would also check that it wasn't disabled [manually](https://www.my-private-network.co.uk/kbhome/openvpn-on-windows-common-issues-no-tap-adapter-available-error/).

Comment: @Cruiser I uninstalled OpenVPN and installed a slightly different UI, openvpn-install-2.3.9-I601-x86_64.exe, and same problem. I did see the TAP Ethernet Adapter being installed. I will try another client.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I install and use openvpn quite often, so the TAP interface missing was the most obvious think I could think of when it speaks of "interface missing". Oh, did you start openvpn with admin right? You need admin rights to configure the TAP interface.